# Deploying heroku app from a subrepository

Tags: git, github, heroku

If I have a github repository **myRepository** and I'm trying to deploy an inside of my **myAwesomeRepository**. How can I deploy my app that is inside **myAwesomeRepository**?

I tried investigating and found something like **git subtree**.

```
myRepository
|-------myAwesomeRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

`git subtree push --prefix myAwesomeRepository heroku master`

You just have to mention the folder name

`git subtree push --prefix <folder> heroku master`

Comment: I keep getting the error "assertion failed:  test tutorial-1 = .\tutorial-1 No new revisions were found"

Comment: Just make sure your subTree name is correct (case sensitive). Also if you are providing a  path then make sure it's correct. Also, make sure that your .gitignore is not ignoring that subtree.